# Bitrix. Как добавить дочернюю страницу элементу каталога?

Tags: битрикс

Ситуация такая:

Есть сайт на битриксе. В нем есть каталог. В каталоге есть товары. У товаров есть возможность оставить отзыв. Сама форма лежит на отдельной странице, переход на которую осуществляется со страницы товара с GET-параметром, содержащем id товара. Иначе говоря:

- товар - https://site.ru/catalog/section-code-path/element/
- страница с отзывами - https://site.ru/feedback?PRODUCT_ID=123

Необходимо сделать так, чтобы страница с отзывами была как бы дочерней к товару, т.е.:

- https://site.ru/catalog/section-code-path/element/feedback/

Как можно подобное реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо добавить новое правило обработки адресов https://site.ru/bitrix/admin/urlrewrite_list.php

Например, так:

Условие: #^/catalog/section-code-path/element/feedback/#

Файл: /feedback/index.php

Тогда обращение по адресу https://site.ru/catalog/section-code-path/element/feedback/?PRODUCT_ID=123 будет обработано как https://site.ru/feedback?PRODUCT_ID=123